# Soft Deletion in Django: get().delete() v/s filter().delete()

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-admin, soft-delete

I recently implemented Soft Delete in Django by overriding `django.db.models.query.QuerySet` and `django.db.models.Manager`.

### QuerySet:

```
class SoftDeleteQuerySet(QuerySet):
    def delete(self):
        super(SoftDeleteQuerySet, self).update(is_deleted=True, deleted=timezone.now())

    def delete_hard(self):
        super(SoftDeleteQuerySet, self).delete()

    def deleted(self):
        super(SoftDeleteQuerySet, self).filter(is_deleted=True)
```

### Manager:

```
class SoftDeletionManager(models.Manager):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.show_deleted = kwargs.pop('show_deleted', False)
        super(SoftDeletionManager, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.show_deleted:
            return SoftDeleteQuerySet(self.model)
        return SoftDeleteQuerySet(self.model).filter(is_deleted=False)

    def delete_hard(self, instance):
        return self.get_queryset().delete_hard()
```

When I delete any object from change_list form using action, this works absolutely fine. But when I go to the detail view and try deleting the object, *it is completely removed from database*.

So far I have figured out that problem is due to **MyModel.objects.get(...).delete()**. Just to make sure I'm not going in the wrong direction, I checked it in python shell:

### ./manage.py shell:

```
>> Status.objects.all().count()
2
>> Status.all_objects.all().count()
4

>> Status.objects.get(pk=4).delete()
>> Status.objects.all().count()
1
>> Status.all_objects.all().count()
3

>> Status.objects.filter(pk=9).delete()
>> Status.objects.all().count()
0
>> Status.all_objects.all().count()
3
```

It would be great if someone can explain me this behaviour and suggest me solution for this.

#### Django 1.6.5

#### Python 3.4.0

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
Status.objects.get(pk=4).delete()
```

is equivalent to this

```
obj = Status.objects.get(pk=4) # obj is now Status object
obj.delete()
```

So in this case the manager methods are not called. You call `delete` directly on object which is not overrided.

However

```
Status.objects.filter(pk=9).delete()
```

is equal to

```
qs = Status.objects.filter(pk=9) # qs is now SoftDeleteQuerySet object
qs.delete()
```

so it does call your method.

Comment: where is this `obj.delete()` method defined then? where does it reside? why is defined separately? and lastly solution? :) Thanks

Comment: it should be defined in `Status` model in your case. Just override it there as well.

Comment: oh I see, completely missed it. Thanks, will try it out.